# An incomplete inner product space with an orthonormal basis that is not a Hamel basis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, hamel-basis

Given any infinite dimensional Hilbert space $X$, the linear span, $Y$, of any orthogonal basis for $X$ is an incomplete inner product subspace of $X$. The orthogonal basis for $X$ is an orthogonal basis and a Hamel basis for $Y$.

What is an example of an incomplete inner product space with an orthonormal basis that is not a Hamel basis?

Comment: Just take the linear span of the $\ell_2$ basis and graft on some element of $\ell_2$ which is not in the linear span, for instance $(1/n)_{n=1}^\infty$